# dereferencing a multi-tiered hash in Perl

Tags: perl, hash

I cannot dereference the %spec_hash
Is it a multilevel hash?

```
#!/perl/bin/perl
use FOOConf; #custom module 
use Data::Dumper ;
FOOConf::makeDBConnection(production);
use strict; 
use warnings; 

my $dbh=$EVTConf::dbh;
my $query = "select e_risk_symbol from gsd_etds where level_name='EXCH_CS' and e_exch_dest='XISX' and e_symbol_comment in ('Bin_6','Bin_56')";

if(!$dbh) {
    print "Error connecting to DataBase; $DBI::errstr\n";
    }  
    my $cur_msg = $dbh->prepare($query) or die "\n\nCould not prepare statement:".$dbh->errstr;
    $cur_msg->execute();
    while (my @row=$cur_msg->fetchrow_array) {
           $spec_hash{'XISX'}{$row[0]}=1;
           }

    while(($key,$value) = each(%spech_hash)) {
        print $key. "," .$value ;
        }
```

I can see what is going into hash :

```
#!/perl/bin/perl
use strict; 
use warnings ; 
use FOOConf; # custom module we use for db access. 
FOOConf::makeDBConnection(production); # amkes a database connection. 
my $dbh=$EVTConf::dbh;
my $query = "select e_risk_symbol from gsd_etds where level_name='EXCH_CS' and e_exch_dest='XISX' and e_symbol_comment in ('Bin_6','Bin_56')";

if(!$dbh) {
    print "Error connecting to DataBase; $DBI::errstr\n";
    }
    my $cur_msg = $dbh->prepare($query) or die "\n\nCould not prepare statement:".$dbh->errstr;
    $cur_msg->execute();
    while (my @row=$cur_msg->fetchrow_array) {
          foreach $row(@row) {
          print "$row ";
          }
    }

     print "\n";
```

this is what i get ;

```
MTG GPS WM JBL ISIL MBI BA ILMN FCEL NDAQ CMS HOLX
INTC CYBX STLD MDT CTSH ASBC AMP KLAC LXK X MON 
SYY HIG UNM AMGN STZ KMP SONC ECA BEBE EAT PLCE 
SPN LAMR PDCO XLP GME CSGP EXC BHP
```

I can see what is getting loaded in to the $spec_hash by walking through the 
@row array, and I can dump the %spec_hash

```
    while (my @row=$cur_msg->fetchrow_array) {
           $spec_hash{'XISX'}{$row[0]}=1;
           }

           print Dumper(%spec_hash)
```

In the dump is XISX the name of the hash and FCEL the key in hash XISX and the value of key FCEL is 1

```
foo@fooserver:/tmp/walt $ ./just_db.row.dumper
$VAR1 = 'XISX';
$VAR2 = {
          'FCEL' => 1,
          'GPS' => 1,  
          'MCO' => 1,
          'DPZ' => 1,
          'WM' => 1,
          'SPLS' => 1,
          'ILMN' => 1,
          'BWLD' => 1,
          'CTSH' => 1,
          'EWU' => 1,
          'MDVN' => 1,
          'PDCO' => 1,
          'AFAM' => 1,
          'SHW' => 1,
```

I just can't dereference

```
 "$spec_hash{'XISX'}{$row[0]}=1;"
```

there is somthing I don't understand about the way this hash is loaded.

Comment: it is easier to read  - what does the \ do before the %spec_hash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this dump to see a better hash structure:

```
print Dumper(\%spec_hash);
```

To dereference you need:

```
 while(my($key,$value) = each(%{$spech_hash{'XISX'}})) {
```

Comment: What kind of hash is this?

Comment: Is the name of the hash %spec_hash{'XISX'} the keys of the hash are the symbols, such as FCEL, SPLS etc. and the value of each key is one?

Comment: is this a multi-level hash of a hash of hashes - naming the demon will help me understand it

Comment: This is a multi dimentional hash. It is a hash of hashes.

Comment: Therefore it has to be dereferenced as such. So yes when you dereference, when you get the value of $spec_hash{'XISX'} you end up of with the hash reference. So you need to dereference that